# Get Max value comparing multiple columns and return specific values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe like:

```
Sequence    Duration1   Value1  Duration2   Value2  Duration3   Value3
1001        145         10      125         53      458         33
1002        475         20      175         54      652         45
1003        685         57      687         87      254         88
1004        125         54      175         96      786         96
1005        475         21      467         32      526         32
1006        325         68      301         54      529         41
1007        125         97      325         85      872         78
1008        129         15      429         41      981         82
1009        547         47      577         52      543         83
1010        666         65      722         63      257         87
```

I want to find the maximum value of Duration in (Duration1,Duration2,Duration3) and return the corresponding Value & Sequence.

My Desired Output:

```
Sequence,Duration3,Value3
1008,    981,      82
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try the following, quite short code, based mainly on *Numpy*:

```
vv = df.iloc[:, 1::2].values
iRow, iCol = np.unravel_index(vv.argmax(), vv.shape)
iCol = iCol * 2 + 1
result = df.iloc[iRow, [0, iCol, iCol + 1]]
```

The result is a *Series*:

```
Sequence     1008
Duration3     981
Value3         82
Name: 7, dtype: int64
```

If you want to "rehape" it (first index values, then actual values),
you can get something like this executing:

```
pd.DataFrame([result.values], columns=result.index)
```

Comment: Though, this is heavily dependent upon the column ordering (I guess that could be ensured with a `.reindex` in the beginning for safety)

Comment: Sir, I liked your answer verymuch. I have a similar question and need your help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58102325/find-max-frequency-for-every-sequence-id

Answer (score 7):

With wide data it can be easier to first reshape with `wide_to_long`. This creates 2 columns `['Duration', 'Value']`, and the MultiIndex tells us which number it was. There is no reliance on any specific column ordering.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.wide_to_long(df, i='Sequence', j='num', stubnames=['Duration', 'Value'])
df.loc[[df.Duration.idxmax()]]

              Duration  Value
Sequence num                 
1008     3         981     82
```

Answer (score 5):

### Without using `numpy` wizardry:

- First, there are some really great solutions to this problem, by others.
- Data will be that provided in the question, as `df`

```py
# find the max value in the Duration columns
max_value = max(df.filter(like='Dur', axis=1).max().tolist())

# get a Boolean match of the dataframe for max_value
df_max = df[df == mv]

# get the row index
max_index = df_max.dropna(how='all').index[0]

# get the column name
max_col = df_max.dropna(axis=1, how='all').columns[0]

# get column index
max_col_index = df.columns.get_loc(max_col)

# final
df.iloc[max_index, [0, max_col_index, max_col_index + 1]]
```

#### Output:

```py
Sequence     1008
Duration3     981
Value3         82
Name: 7, dtype: int64
```

## Update

- Last night, actually 4 a.m., I dismissed a better solution, because I was overly tired.

  - I used `max_value = max(df.filter(like='Dur', axis=1).max().tolist())`, to return the maximum value within the `Duration` columns
  - Instead of `max_col_name = df.filter(like='Dur', axis=1).max().idxmax()`, to return the column name where the maximum value occurs
  - I did that because my addled brain told me I was returning the max value of the column names, instead of the maximum value in the column.  For example:

```py
test = ['Duration5', 'Duration2', 'Duration3']
print(max(test))
>>> 'Duration5'
```

- This is why being overtired, is a poor problem solving condition
- With sleep, and coffee, a more efficient solution

  - Similar to others, in the use of `idmax`

### New & Improved Solution:

```py
# column name with max duration value
max_col_name = df.filter(like='Dur', axis=1).max().idxmax()

# index of max_col_name
max_col_idx =df.columns.get_loc(max_col_name)

# row index of max value in max_col_name
max_row_idx = df[max_col_name].idxmax()

# output with .loc
df.iloc[max_row_idx, [0, max_col_idx, max_col_idx + 1 ]]
```

#### Output:

```py
Sequence     1008
Duration3     981
Value3         82
Name: 7, dtype: int64
```

#### Methods used:

- [`pandas.DataFrame.max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.max.html)
- [`pandas.DataFrame.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html)
- [`pandas.DataFrame.idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html)
- [`pandas.Index.get_loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html)
- [`pandas.DataFrame.iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html)

Comment: It should be noted that this does a bunch of redundant computation over the dataframe.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq I think this party was more about seeing how many ways this problem could be solved. This isn’t the most elegant solution, but I’m satisfied that I learned something from my effort and from the other answers. Also, those are some great photos on your profile.

Answer (score 4):

You can obtain the index of the maximum value of a column using:

```
>>> idx = df['Duration3'].idxmax()
>>> idx
7
```

And the relevant columns only using:

```
>>> df_cols = df[['Sequence', 'Duration3', 'Value3']]
>>> df_cols.loc[idx]
Sequence     1008
Duration3     981
Value3         82
Name: 7, dtype: int64
```

So, simply wrap all that up into one nice function:

```
def get_max(df, i):
    idx = df[f'Duration{i}'].idxmax()
    df_cols = df[['Sequence', f'Duration{i}', f'Value{i}']]
    return df_cols.loc[idx]
```

And loop over `1..3`:

```
>>> max_rows = [get_max(i) for i in range(1, 4)]
>>> print('\n\n'.join(map(str, max_rows)))
Sequence     1003
Duration1     685
Value1         57
Name: 2, dtype: int64

Sequence     1010
Duration2     722
Value2         63
Name: 9, dtype: int64

Sequence     1008
Duration3     981
Value3         82
Name: 7, dtype: int64
```

If you want to reduce these 3 down to a single maximum row, you can do the following:

```
>>> pairs = enumerate(max_rows, 1)
>>> by_duration = lambda x: x[1][f'Duration{x[0]}']
>>> i, max_row = max(pairs, key=by_duration)
>>> max_row
Sequence     1008
Duration3     981
Value3         82
Name: 7, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Sir, is it possible to filter the Max Duration only and result as "Sequence,Duration3,Value3"
"1008,    981,      82"

Answer (score 4):

If I understand the question correctly, given the followind dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Seq': [1, 2, 3], 'Dur1': [2, 7, 3],'Val1': ['x', 'y', 'z'],'Dur2': [3, 5, 1], 'Val2': ['a', 'b', 'c']})
    Seq  Dur1 Val1  Dur2 Val2
0    1     2    x     3    a
1    2     7    y     5    b
2    3     3    z     1    c
```

These 5 lines of code solve your problem:

```
dur_col = [col_name for col_name in df.columns if col_name.startswith('Dur')] # ['Dur1', 'Dur2'] 
max_dur_name = df.loc[:, dur_col].max().idxmax()
val_name = "Val" + str([int(s) for s in max_dur_name if s.isdigit()][0])

filter_col = ['Seq', max_dur_name, val_name]

df_res = df[filter_col].sort_values(max_dur_name, ascending=False).head(1)
```

And you get:

```
   Seq  Dur1 Val1 
1    2     7    y
```

#### Code explanation:

I automatically get the columns that start with 'Dur', and I find the column name with a longer duration:

```
dur_col = [col_name for col_name in df.columns if col_name.startswith('Dur')] # ['Dur1', 'Dur2'] 
max_dur_name = df.loc[:, dur_col].max().idxmax()
val_name = "Val" + str([int(s) for s in max_dur_name if s.isdigit()][0])
```

Choose the columns I'm interested in:

```
filter_col = ['Seq', max_dur_name, val_name]
```

Filter the columns that interest me, I order for `max_dur_name` and I get the search result:

```
df_res = df[filter_col].sort_values(max_dur_name, ascending=False).head(1)

# output:
   Seq  Dur1 Val1 
1    2     7    y
```

Comment: Sir, my requirement is like if Dur1 is having max value then out put will have only "Seq","Dur1 "Val1". if Dur2 is having max value then output will be "Seq","Dur2 "Val2"

Answer (score 4):

Here is another way ,

```
m=df.set_index('Sequence') #set Sequence as index
n=m.filter(like='Duration') #gets all columns with the name Duration
s=n.idxmax()[n.eq(n.values.max()).any()]
#output Duration3    1008
d = dict(zip(m.columns[::2],m.columns[1::2])) #create a mapper dict
#{'Duration1': 'Value1', 'Duration2': 'Value2', 'Duration3': 'Value3'}
final=m.loc[s.values,s.index.union(s.index.map(d))].reset_index()
```

---

```
   Sequence  Duration3  Value3
0      1008        981      82
```

Answer (score 4):

A bit similar to [@Massifox's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58039054/10426037), but I think is different enough to be worthy to be added.

```
mvc = df[[name for name in df.columns if 'Duration' in name]].max().idxmax()
mvidx = df[mvc].idxmax()
valuecol = 'Value' + mvc[-1]
df.loc[mvidx, ['Sequence', mvc, valuecol]]
```

1. First I get the column name `mvc` where the maximum value is located (`mvc` is `'Durantion3'` following your example).
2. Then I get the row index `mvidx` of the maximum value (`mvidx` is `7`).
3. Then I build the correct Value column (`valuecol` is `'Value3'`).
4. Finally with `loc` I select the desired output, which is:

   ```
   Sequence     1008
   Duration3     981
   Value3         82
   Name: 7, dtype: int64
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
if len(df[df[dur1]>=df[dur2].max()])==0:
    if len(df[df[dur2]>=df[dur3].max()])==0:
        print(df[df[dur3].idmax()][[seq,dur3,val3]])
    else:
        print(df[df[dur2].idmax()][[seq,dur2,val2]])
else:
   if len(df[df[dur1]>=df[dur3].max()])==0:
       print(df[df[dur3].idmax()][[seq,dur3,val3]])
   else:
       print(df[df[dur1].idmax()][[seq,dur1,val1]])
```