# Find Max Frequency for every Sequence_ID

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, list-comprehension

I have a Dataframe Like:

```
Time         Frq_1   Seq_1       Frq_2   Seq_2       Frq_3   Seq_3
12:43:04     -       30,668      -       30,670      4,620   30,671 
12:46:05     -       30,699      -       30,699      3,280   30,700 
12:46:17     4,200   30,700      -       30,704      -       30,704 
12:46:18     3,060   30,700      4,200   30,700      -       30,700 
12:46:18     3,060   30,700      4,200   30,700      -       30,700 
12:46:19     3,060   30,700      4,220   30,700      -       30,700 
12:46:20     3,060   30,700      4,240   30,700      -       30,700 
12:46:37     -       30,698      -       30,699      3,060   30,700 
12:46:38     -       30,699      3,060   30,700      4,600   30,700 
12:47:19     -       30,668      -       30,669      -       30,669 
12:47:20     -       30,667      -       30,667      -       30,668 
12:47:20     -       30,667      -       30,667      -       30,668 
12:47:21     -       30,667      -       30,667      -       30,668 
12:47:21     -       30,665      -       30,665      -       30,665 
12:47:22     -       30,665      -       30,665      -       30,665 
12:48:35     -       30,688      -       30,690      3,020   30,690 
12:49:29     4,160   30,690      -       30,691      -       30,693
```

I want check the total dataframe and find the result with below condition:

> 1. Sequence_ID for which Frequency is not null
> 2. Sequence_ID for which Frequency is Max (in case of multiple Sequence_ID with non zero Frequency)

I want my result as below:

```
Time         Sequence_ID    Frequency
12:43:04     4,620          30,671 
12:46:18     4,200          30,700 
12:49:29     4,160          30,690
```

> Time = correspond to row of (Sequence_ID & Frequency)

Comment: In the future, I suggest you make an attempt to focus the problem as much as you can. There's **a lot** going on here; numbers not stored as numeric types, missing data not properly represented, and then the logic you truly want to implement. As you can see, answers to these types of questions get muddied by all of the pre-processing and peripheral steps that need to be taken, which makes these questions far less useful to future users. This leads to downvotes on the question, and frequently answers not receiving as many upvotes as they otherwise would, despite the heroic effort required.

Comment: Sorry. I have edited the Question as required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turned out to be quite involved. Here we go anyway:

```
long_df = pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(), stubnames=['Seq_', 'Frq_'], 
                          suffix='\d+', i='index', j='j')
long_df['Frq_'] = pd.to_numeric(long_df.Frq_.str.replace(',','.')
                                .replace('-',float('nan')))
long_df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
ix = long_df.groupby('Seq_').Frq_.idxmax()
```

---

```
print(long_df.loc[ix[ix.notna()].values.astype(int)])

     Time      Seq_   Frq_
34  12:43:04  30,671  4.62
16  12:49:29  30,690  4.16
42  12:46:38  30,700  4.60
```

Seems like for the sequence `30,700`, the highest frequency is `4.60`, not `4.20`

---

The first step is to collapse the dataframe into three rows, one for the `Time`, another for the sequence and for the frequency. We can use `pd.wide_to_long` with the stubnames `['Seq_', 'Frq_']`:

```
long_df = pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(), stubnames=['Seq_', 'Frq_'], 
                              suffix='\d+', i='index', j='j')

print(long_df)

            Time    Seq_   Frq_
index j                         
0     1  12:43:04  30,668      -
1     1  12:46:05  30,699      -
2     1  12:46:17  30,700  4,200
3     1  12:46:18  30,700  3,060
4     1  12:46:18  30,700  3,060
5     1  12:46:19  30,700  3,060
6     1  12:46:20  30,700  3,060
7     1  12:46:37  30,698      -
8     1  12:46:38  30,699      -
9     1  12:47:19  30,668      -
10    1  12:47:20  30,667      -
11    1  12:47:20  30,667      -
12    1  12:47:21  30,667      -
13    1  12:47:21  30,665      -
14    1  12:47:22  30,665      -
15    1  12:48:35  30,688      -
16    1  12:49:29  30,690  4,160
...
```

The next step is to cast to float the fequencies to `float`, to be able to find the maximum values:

```
long_df['Frq_'] = pd.to_numeric(long_df.Frq_.str.replace(',','.')
                                    .replace('-',float('nan')))

print(long_df)

          Time    Seq_  Frq_
index j                        
0     1  12:43:04  30,668   NaN
1     1  12:46:05  30,699   NaN
2     1  12:46:17  30,700  4.20
3     1  12:46:18  30,700  3.06
4     1  12:46:18  30,700  3.06
5     1  12:46:19  30,700  3.06
6     1  12:46:20  30,700  3.06
7     1  12:46:37  30,698   NaN
...
```

Then we can groupby `Seq_` and find the indices with the highest values. One could also think of using `max`, but this would remove the `Time` column.

```
long_df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
ix = long_df.groupby('Seq_').Frq_.idxmax()
```

And finally index based on the above:

```
print(long_df.loc[ix[ix.notna()].values.astype(int)])

     Time      Seq_   Frq_
34  12:43:04  30,671  4.62
16  12:49:29  30,690  4.16
42  12:46:38  30,700  4.60
```

Comment: Sorry Sir for some delay. I have edited the question and corrected the "-" and "," values. Actually I have copied the values from excel.

Comment: Especially having given this amount of work in providing a good answer, it is not a good practive to *change the question*, since now my answer does not seem to properly solve your problem. Please post a new question with the changes (a separate post), and accept this one as it seemed to solve you problem @RohitLambaK

Comment: I am extremely Sorry Sir. I have not changed the question. Just corrected the comma and dash values. others remain same.